# Convert ADF Fusion web application to Mobile app?

Tags: oracle-adf, oracle-adf-mobile

Can I Covert Existing ADF Fusion web application  To Mobile Application

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Mobile Application Framework (MAF) the answer is no.
The UI of MAF, while it shares similar concepts: Taskflows and Drag and Drop property-based components - the implementations are completely different. MAF uses AMX pages which generate HTML5, JS and CSS on the fly on the device and ADF Faces uses JSF-based pages.
If you deploy your ADF BC model as a RESTful service using JDev 12.2.1 you can consume it, like any other RESTful web service, in MAF.
The larger question is..why? A Desktop application is a very different design paradigm than mobile-friendly. The entire application UI design should be re-thought using the tips and guidance of [Oracle Alta UI](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/ux/middleware/alta/index.html).